# Desktop Touch screen iPhone style scrolling in IE with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, internet-explorer, mobile-website

Is it possible to make a web page to scroll up and down just like iPhone does in IE with jquery (or any other js tool that has not issues with jquery)?

Comment: This is what i want https://github.com/neave/touch-scroll but for IE

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch is a mobile UI framework with support for momentum scrolling built in. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Look for the example on lists under user interface on the left menu

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/ shows blank page in IE. To make it clear, all i want to do is to add scroller feature to my webpage, not to build it from scratch.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE, it works in Android and Iphone. You can view it online with Chrome or Safari. Do you want this to work on desktop browsers?

Comment: I want to use it in a kiosk application that has embbeded IE desktop browser (windows default). So it must be IE.